# how to access ajax returned value in php

Tags: php, ajax

Hi I am really new to web development. I would like to know how I can access a ajax returned value in php. 
When i select an option from my drop down i get another dropdown using ajax. But I would like to use the value on the page using php.

```
      Practice Name : 
    <select name="practiceName" id="practiceName" onchange="showAssociate(this.value)">
    <option value="">Select an option</option>
 <option value="abc">abc</option>
 <option value="xyz">xyz</option>


    </select>
<p>

<div id="associate">
</div>
```

The ajax code is:

```
    function showAssociate(str)
{
if (str=="")
{
document.getElementById("associate").innerHTML="";
return;
} 
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
{// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
 }
else
{// code for IE6, IE5
xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
{
if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
{
document.getElementById("associate").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
}
}
xmlhttp.open("GET","getAssociate.php?q="+str,true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
```

The ajax is returning the desired drop box and values in the div 'associate' but how can i use those values in php while submitting the form? I just need to access and echo it somewhere on the screen. please do help.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: shorten and format your code. find a way to ask your question in a sentance or less.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the data that was retrieved via ajax to be sent along with the form, you can populate a hidden input, so that the data will be transported in the form submission.

```
<input type="hidden" id="data" name="data" value="" />
```

In the Javascript, populate its value:

```
document.getElementById("associate").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
document.getElementById("data").value = xmlhttp.responseText;
```

On the PHP side when you handle the form submission, it will be present in `$_POST['data']` (assuming the form's method is `POST`).